# Row Index based on separate columns' unique values

Tags: r, match

My data looks like below:

```
dat <- structure(list(col1 = c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2"),  
                    col2= c("te", "te", "au", "au", "sb", "sb", "te", "te", "te", "te", "te", "au", "au", "sb", "sb", "sb"), 
                    col3 = c("ad", "ak", "ap", "tp", "ad", "cd", "mk", "ml", "an", "ad", "ak", "ap", "kk", "jj", "cd", "cp")),
               .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
dat
   col1 col2 col3
1    a1   te   ad
2    a1   te   ak
3    a1   au   ap
4    a1   au   tp
5    a1   sb   ad
6    a1   sb   cd
7    a2   te   mk
8    a2   te   ml
9    a2   te   an
10   a2   te   ad
11   a2   te   ak
12   a2   au   ap
13   a2   au   kk
14   a2   sb   jj
15   a2   sb   cd
16   a2   sb   cp
```

I need to provide row index number based on unique column entries. For example, `row1` and `row2` has unique values in `col1` and `col2`. Values in `col3` varies for these two rows. I want to put 1, and 2 as index number for these two rows. The output will be like this:

```
   col1 col2 col3 rowind
1    a1   te   ad      1
2    a1   te   ak      2
3    a1   au   ap      1
4    a1   au   tp      2
5    a1   sb   ad      1
6    a1   sb   cd      2
7    a2   te   mk      1
8    a2   te   ml      2
9    a2   te   an      3
10   a2   te   ad      4
11   a2   te   ak      5
12   a2   au   ap      1
13   a2   au   kk      2
14   a2   sb   jj      1
15   a2   sb   cd      2
16   a2   sb   cp      3
```

I am trying to use `match` functions. However, still not working.

Comment: Assuming your second column is called `col2`, using `dplyr`, you can do `dat %>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  mutate(rowind = row_number())` Or `dat$rowind <- with(dat, ave(seq_along(col1), col1, col2, FUN = seq_along))` in base R.

Comment: Yes, it answers my question.